# how to check which GWT library i am Using

Tags: gwt

I want to know which GWT library is been using in a project and also if the project is working on GWT or GXT ,  can you please guide me where to check this, secondly if there's some website where we can found list of all GWT libraries

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your are using Eclipse, you can check the version by
Project->Properties->Google->Web Toolkit GWT SDK
If not, check the classpath to see where your libs are coming from

Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the *.gwt.xml file and if you have gxt referenced then you have gxt (doesn't meant that you are using it though) - the simplest way to see if you are using gxt widgets is to look at the widgets that you have coded and look at the class reference - if it has gxt in the reference path then it is a gxt library...